# Android - How can I update data or UI in my Activity when Push Notification FCM is received?

Tags: java, android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I have the following `FirebaseMessagingService` which works fine when I get a push notification and the app is in foreground:

```
public class _FCMService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
   @Override
   public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
      if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
         // Log.i(TAG, "PUSH PAYLOAD: " + remoteMessage.getData());

         JSONObject pushData = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData());
         pushType = pushData.optString("pushType");
         pushMessage = pushData.optString("body");
         Log.i(TAG, "ON PUSH RECEIVED - pushType: " + pushType);
         Log.i(TAG, "ON PUSH RECEIVED - pushMessage: " + pushMessage);


         Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
         NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                 .setContentText(pushMessage)
                 .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle())
                 .setAutoCancel(true)
                 .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                 .setSound(defaultSoundUri);
         NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
         assert notificationManager != null;
         notificationManager.notify(0 , notificationBuilder.build());
      }
   }



   @Override
   public void onNewToken(@NotNull String token) {
      Log.i(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + token);
      ANDROID_DEVICE_TOKEN = token;
   }
}
```

So, If I receive a push, the Logcat prints out the notification's body and (if present) the `pushType` string.

What I would need to do is to make my other Activity update data when push is received, as well as get the `pushMessage` and `pushType` strings.

I know how to do that in iOS Swift - by using `NotificationCenter` - but have no idea about Android, I've tried `LocalBroadcaster`, but no success.

Answer (score 5):

`LocalBroadcastManager` is now deprecated!

You can use `LiveData` implementation in a static reference and observe it in the `Activity` or `Fragment`

```
public class NotificationService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        
        Notification.
                    getInstance().
                    addOrder(remoteMessage.getData().get("id"));
        
    }

    public static class Notification {
        private static Notification instance;
        private MutableLiveData<String> newOrder;

        private Notification() {
            newOrder = new MutableLiveData<>();
        }

        public static Notification getInstance() {
            if(instance == null){
                instance = new Notification();
            }
            return instance;
        }

        public LiveData<String> getNewOrder() {
            return newOrder;
        }

        public void addOrder(String orderID){
            newOrder.postValue(orderID);
        }
    }
}
```

And In the `Activity` or `Fragment`:

```
NotificationService.
   Notification.
       getInstance().
       getNewOrder().
       observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
           @Override
           public void onChanged(String s) {
               //TODO: update your ui here...
           }
       });
```

Comment: `Activity` class does not have `getViewLifecycleOwner` method. I have fixed it by inheriting from `AppCompatActivity` instead and passing `this` instead of calling that method.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a  `.setContentIntent(NotificationChannelUtil.createPendingIntent(this, pushMessage, pushType))` to your notificaitionBuilder.

Where that function is inside an util class like:

```
public class NotificationChannelUtil {

    private NotificationChannelUtil() {}

 public static PendingIntent createPendingIntent(Context context, String pushMessage, String pushType) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourWantedActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("pushMessage", pushMessage);
        intent.putExtra("pushType", pushType);
        return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0 /* request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but then how to I call it on my Activity? I mean, how do I get the pushMessage string and Logcat it, for example?

Comment: Intent intent = getIntent();
String pushMessage = intent.getStringExtra("pushMessage");
String pushType = intent.getStringExtra("pushType");

Comment: Thanks, but it gives me "null" when I enter my Activity, after receiving a push. Here's the scenario: I'm in a chat activity, it's open and I'm interacting with it, then I get a push notification and I need to automatically have my Activity to get it and call a function to refresh data, you know what I mean? Maybe I need an Observer, something like that, that keeps listening to push events

Comment: This pending notification works when you click on the notification! It does not matter if it's in foreground or background. If you want to be automatically redirected to your Activity, you should consider to create a similar simple Intent with the same "putExtra" and call it inside "onMessagedReceived" - but you should test it if it works ok in background and foreground. (if not, make that simple Intent only if app is in foreground and use my way with PendingIntent otherwise)

Comment: "This pending notification works when you click on the notification!" -> Ok, I knew that, so that wasn't my question, I need to get push data when my Activity is open. In iOS you can use NotificationCentter observer, which keeps listening for events like pushes. Is there a way to do it on Android too?

Comment: Not sure about how you need to do it. Usually when you want to modified a data you also want to open that activity.. I think you should use some LiveData so you can observe it, as you said it's done in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to my issue, which actually looks similar to the iOS `NotificationCenter` instance. I've added this class into my _FCMService.java file:

```
class NotificationCenter {
   private static NotificationCenter _instance;
   private HashMap<String, ArrayList<Runnable>> registredObjects;
   private NotificationCenter(){
      registredObjects = new HashMap<>();
   }

   //returning the reference
   static synchronized NotificationCenter defaultCenter(){
      if(_instance == null)
         _instance = new NotificationCenter();
      return _instance;
   }

   synchronized void addFunctionForNotification(String notificationName, Runnable r){
      ArrayList<Runnable> list = registredObjects.get(notificationName);
      if(list == null) {
         list = new ArrayList<Runnable>();
         registredObjects.put(notificationName, list);
      }
      list.add(r);
   }

   public synchronized void removeFunctionForNotification(String notificationName, Runnable r){
      ArrayList<Runnable> list = registredObjects.get(notificationName);
      if(list != null) {
         list.remove(r);
      }
   }

   synchronized void postNotification(String notificationName){
      ArrayList<Runnable> list = registredObjects.get(notificationName);
      if(list != null) {
         for(Runnable r: list)
            r.run();
      }
   }
}
```

Then I've called it inside the `onMessageReceived()` function:

```
NotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotification("pushNotif");
```

Lastly, I've added the observer into the `onStart()` function of my Activity as it follows:

```
@Override
   protected void onStart() {
      super.onStart();

      // Start NotificationCenter to observe for new messages
      NotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addFunctionForNotification("pushNotif", new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "Obj Details -> pushMessage: " + pushMessage + "\npushType" + pushType);

      }});
   }
```

It works smoothly, hoper this helps somebody else.